# Is it acceptible to generate a new view from a current view in psql

Tags: postgresql

The example is below: is it plausible to generate view v_nonwinners upon another v_show_win?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (
    name TEXT,
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS matches (
    player1_id int,
    player2_id int,
    winner_id int,
    match_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE VIEW v_show_win AS
    select * from players left join matches
    on players.id=matches.player1_id or players.id=matches.player2_id;
CREATE VIEW v_nonwinners AS
    select id,winner from v_show_win
    where winner is null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use views many levels deep, and it's often useful to do so.

There is generally minimal performance impact, since views get inlined during query processing.